# MongoDB $all operator returns nothing in mongo shell or compass when multiple items are passed into its array

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get the documents that contains any of the specified or all the keywords in their keywords array. When I just pass one keyword in the array for `$all` operator, it
returns only one document and not all of them that has that keyword. Shown below are the problems for me with `$all` operator

**LIST OF COURES IN MY MONGO DB**

**1**
`course: CSS keywords: ['css', 'sass', 'html', 'js']`

**2**
`course: Node.JS keywords: ['nodejs', 'javascript', 'express', 'mongoose']`

**3**
`course: JavaScript keywords: ['javascript', 'api', 'promises']`

**PROBLEMS**

**1**
`db.courses.find({keywords: {$all: ["css", "sass"] } })`
Returns nothing (should have returned CSS course)

2
`db.courses.find({keywords: {$all: ["css"] } })`
Returns CSS course [Only one document]

3
`db.courses.find({keywords: {$all: ["javascript"] } })`
Returns Node.JS course (should also have returned JavaScript course)

4
`db.courses.find({keywords: {$all: ["javascript", "nodejs"] } })`
Returns Node.JS course only (should also have returned JavaScript course)

5
`db.courses.find({keywords: {$all: ["javascript", "css"] } })`
Returns nothing (should have returned CSS and JavaScript course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB [`$all`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator behaves differently from what you seem to expect: (emphasis mine)

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains **all** the specified elements.

But instead of matching *all* values, you seem to look to match *at least one of them* (i.e. that the intersection of the query items and document items is not empty).

In that case, you should rather use the [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator: (emphasis mine)

> The `$in` operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals **any** value in the specified array.
>
> [...]
>
> If the field holds an array, then the `$in` operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains **at least one element** that matches a value in the specified array

So for example for your 5th query case:

```js
db.collection.find({
  keywords: {
    $in: [ // instead of $all operator
      "javascript",
      "nodejs"
    ]
  }
})

// Result: "Node.JS" and "JavaScript" documents
```

Live demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXXKpBjQg-N

Comment: But on the documentation, [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/], they have achieved the same goal with $all operator. I don't know what that mean.

Comment: If you refer to [Examples > Use `$all` to Match Values](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use--all-to-match-values), notice that the found documents contain _all_ queried tags (possibly more)